# Google Cloud: Build always fails, MANIFEST_UNKNOWN error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to deploy an app engine application, but no matter which code I'm trying to deploy, even if it's taken from their samples at:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples

I get the same error:

```
Step #1: error building image: getting stage builder for stage 0: MANIFEST_UNKNOWN: "Manifest with digest 'sha256:249859465bcde1cb15128ff0d9eb2bb54de67f72a834a7576e6649cfe0a27698' has media type 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json', but client accepts 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json'."
```

I'm not good at devops, so no idea howto work this around

Comment: Can you provide more details? Which command are you perform? What's the version? What the content of your app.yaml file,...

Comment: We would need the details to move on. Please provide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue recently. After some digging, it turns out that the issue was reported on the GCP Issue Tracker already: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171756486

As a workaround update the `app.yaml` file to contain `runtime: go1.13`.

**Update:**

Deploying with `runtime: go1.13` only works for the first run.
It will still fail when attempting to re-deploy.

**Update 2:**

The Google team has rolled back the issue on their side. ([source](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171756486))

To make it work you will need to downgrade your `gcloud` to version `315.0.0`:

```
gcloud components update --version 315.0.0
```

After that, the deployment will proceed as usual.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue when deploying on AppEngine Flexible today.
I don't think it's something you can do.
I opened an issue on github hopefully the google cloud team will fix it fast.

For info, the issue the OP has is that when running `gcloud app deploy app.yaml`  he expects the app do be deployed.

Cloud Build tries to fetch an image that has a media type it does not understand.

Got: `application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json`
Expected: `application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json`

```
Step #0: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/go1-builder@sha256:7b53332a8e6418ba9a3f123c29dd5fe075504d0f9c0b683edfc7e7b75cd27822
Finished Step #0
Starting Step #1
Step #1: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor@sha256:f87c11770a4d3ed33436508d206c584812cd656e6ed08eda1cff5c1ee44f5870
Step #1: INFO[0000] Downloading base image gcr.io/distroless/base@sha256:884ac2144c3ee154bd67271e99bc6ef00f430092750167729b0321ab55fde5ec 
Step #1: error building image: getting stage builder for stage 0: MANIFEST_UNKNOWN: "Manifest with digest 'sha256:884ac2144c3ee154bd67271e99bc6ef00f430092750167729b0321ab55fde5ec' has media type 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json', but client accepts 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json'."
```

Answer (score 2):

Google responded to this [bug ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171756486#comment12) saying to downgrade to gcloud 315.0.0 which i just tested and it worked.

`gcloud components update --version 315.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and figure it up by adding

> service: default

in my app.yaml